Salesforce Security Review - Clickjacking. Hardcoded CSS with position, float, height and width, best approach to refactor?
We have inherited a code base which makes use of bouquet of CSS which Salesforce doesn't recommend i.e. position:absolute, float, hard-coded width and height.
Some of these are part of custom CSS files used as static resources and referenced in various LWCs.
There were hardcoded inline CSS as well, which we have removed now, but for other places where we are not using grids or lightning layouts we have various divs styled with above mentioned attributes and making any changes to those with position:relative just breaks it and there is overlapping of characters.
Understanding we may need to refactor the whole code, is there a different approach to fix the issues highlighted ?

Is it safe to use slds-is-absolute ?
Is it safe if the components are only available for logged in users and hence we can mention these as false positives ?
If a single composite master lwc with multiple child LWCs are being used to fill the whole page and if parent lwc follows slds, can child components (not exposed) use fixed and absolute ?

Refactoring the complete components will take substantial amount of time. Previous code base was not planned or designed keeping mobile form factor in mind and somehow they had cleared the review once before.
Looking for some suggestion or a tested strategy which could work to resolve these issues ?

Going the route of SLDS is basically the only approach you have open to do some positioning and related styling. You will fail if you try to use absolute positioning, though you may succeed with relative positioning. As to ensuring mobile compatibility, use the slds grid to "position" stuff in a responsive way would be the approach I would recommend.

Thank you for the response.  This was what I was afraid of, it does need a lot of refactoring of entire code base. Sigh.    Does discussing with Salesforce ahead via Office Hour Session would help?
